# Two planes which very close to each other

Tags: javascript, three.js

i have got a problem with 2 planes which are very close to each other.

One of the planes is causing glitches or even disappearing on certain point of view.

Here is the code:

```
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 16, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 50000 );
camera.position.set(8000, 4000, 13000);

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
controls.minPolarAngle = 0
controls.maxPolarAngle = (Math.PI / 2) - 0.05;

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 7000, 7000 ),  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial);
mesh.position.y = 0;
mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
mesh.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( mesh );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000, 2000 ),  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00}));
mesh.position.y = 5;
mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
mesh.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( mesh );

}

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
controls.update();
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mae1storm/2hLjn1t5/1/

What can i do to fix this problem?

Sorry for my bad english, Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the depth testing. These planes are so close together that their depth values are the same at some points, so the rasterizer can't really decide which one is in front of which. To solce this problem you have to either increase the distance between the two planes, or cur a whole in the bigger plane with the size of the smaller plan. Or in this case specifically, use a texture instead.

Also your scene is huge, which contributes to the precision issues. Scale it way down and you should be fine again. If your scene would be like 1/100th of the size it will work a lot better.

Comment: Thank You for answer. When i use MeshPhongMaterial with texture map, the problem remains. Increasing distance between the planes works, but i need it to be as close as possible(. Hole in the bigger plane is not an option too, because the small plane is intended to move(.

Comment: the suggestion with the texture was actually meant so that you are left with one plane, where the second plane is only existing as a texture on the first plane. Anyway, just scale it down to 1/100th the size and it should work fine.

Comment: oh, i see. Tried to scale to 1/10th and it works) Thank You)

Comment: in addition your camera far plane value is very big contributing negatively to the depth buffer resolution. Make it as tight as possible around your scene extents.